# How to import data with fixed column widths with gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a simple way with gnuplot to import data with fixed widths of the columns?

The problem is that columns could be empty, so importing with `set datafile separator whitespace` will not work correctly.
I'm aware that you can preprocess data with external tools like awk, sed, etc. but I'm wondering if there might be a simple platform independent *gnuplot-only* solution.

The solution I've come up with is a bit lengthy, but at least it seems to work. If there is a simpler gnuplot-way please let me know.

**Code:**

```
### data with fixed column widths
reset session

$DataRaw <<EOD
# Data with fixed but also empty columns
#0000000011111111112222222222333333333344444
#2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
#--6-||----11---||--7--||-----12---||--8---|
   1.1     1.2222   1.03   some Text   1.555
   2.1    -2.2222                     -2.555
  -3.1     3.2222  -3.03   more text   3.555
   4.1             -4.03              -4.555
                             no data   0.000
   6.1    -6.2222   6.03  no comment  -6.555
EOD

# define the widths of the columns
array FixCols[5] = [6,11,7,12,8]
set datafile separator "\n"
CommentChar = "#"
Separator = ','

# define strip() function workaround to remove spaces at beginning and end of a string
strip(s) = (STRP_a=1, STRP_b=1, \
           sum [STRP_i=1:strlen(s)] ((s[STRP_i:STRP_i] eq " ") ? \
               (STRP_a>0  ? STRP_a=STRP_a+1 : 0) : (STRP_a=-abs(STRP_a), STRP_b=STRP_i) \
           ), s[abs(STRP_a):STRP_b] )

set print $Data
    do for [i=1:|$DataRaw|] {
        if ($DataRaw[i][1:1] ne CommentChar) {
            Line = ''
            Start = 1
            do for [j=1:|FixCols|] {
                End = Start + FixCols[j]-1
                Line = Line.strip($DataRaw[i][Start:End]).(j<|FixCols| ? Separator : "")
                Start = Start + FixCols[j]
            }
            print Line
        }
        else { print $DataRaw[i]}  # print the unchanged commented line
    }
set print

print $Data
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
# Data with fixed but also empty columns
#0000000011111111112222222222333333333344444
#2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
#--6-||----11---||--7--||-----12---||--8---|
1.1,1.2222,1.03,some Text,1.555
2.1,-2.2222,,,-2.555
-3.1,3.2222,-3.03,more text,3.555
4.1,,-4.03,,-4.555
,,,no data,0.000
6.1,-6.2222,6.03,no comment,-6.555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution (compared to the one in the question) which also requires gnuplot>=5.2.0  because it is using indexing of datablocks. It will simply **insert** separators (here: comma) at the appropriate locations and print it to a new table which can then easily be plotted via `set datafile separator ','`.

Other attempts for earlier gnuplot versions parsing the original table using, e.g. `set datafile separator "\t"` and `strcol(1)` will fail because gnuplot will always strip leading and trailing spaces, i.e. in the example below the correct reading of line 9 will always fail.

I am aware that I could use external tools to preprocess the data, but if possible I prefer *gnuplot-only* and hence ensure platform-independence.

**Script:**

```
### data with fixed column widths
reset session

$DataInput <<EOD
# Data with fixed but also empty columns
#0000000011111111112222222222333333333344444
#2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
#--6-||----11---||--7--||-----12---||--8---|
  -1.1     1.2222   1.03   some Text   1.555
   2.1    -2.2222                     -2.555
   3.1     3.2222  -3.03   more text   3.555
   4.1             -4.03              -4.555
                             no data   0.000
   6.1    -6.2222   6.03  no comment  -6.555
EOD

colWidths    = "6 11 7 12 8"  # specify the fixed column widths
commentChar  = "#"
colSeparator = ','
set datafile separator "\n"

insertSeparators(s) = (s0='', p0=1, sum [_i=1:5] (p1=p0+word(colWidths,_i), \
    s0 = s0.s[p0:p1-1].colSeparator, p0=p1, 0), s0[1:strlen(s0)-1])

set print $Data
    do for [i=1:|$DataInput|] {
        if ($DataInput[i][1:1] eq commentChar) { print ($DataInput[i]) }
        else { print insertSeparators($DataInput[i]) }
    }
set print
print $Data

set offset 1,1,1,1
set datafile separator colSeparator

plot $Data u 1:5 w lp pt 7 lc "red", \
        '' u 1:5:4 w labels offset 0,0.8
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
# Data with fixed but also empty columns
#0000000011111111112222222222333333333344444
#2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
#--6-||----11---||--7--||-----12---||--8---|
  -1.1,     1.2222,   1.03,   some Text,   1.555
   2.1,    -2.2222,       ,            ,  -2.555
   3.1,     3.2222,  -3.03,   more text,   3.555
   4.1,           ,  -4.03,            ,  -4.555
      ,           ,       ,     no data,   0.000
   6.1,    -6.2222,   6.03,  no comment,  -6.555
```

[image]

**Addition:**

For completeness, here is an alternative approach:

- typically, data is provided in a file, but the solutions above and the following require the data in a datablock. This can be achieved by [this script snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65316744/7295599).
- the following script defines functions `fcol()` and `fstrcol()`, basically as replacement for `column()` and `strcol()`, just for fixed length columns.
- since `real('')` will return an error and `real(' ')` will return `0.0` (at least for gnuplot<=5.5), `NaN` is added to each substring in `fcol()`, hence returning `NaN` for these cases.

**Data:** `SO58245920.dat`

```
# Data with fixed but also empty columns
#0000000011111111112222222222333333333344444
#2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
#--6-||----11---||--7--||-----12---||--8---|
  -1.1     1.2222   1.03   some Text   1.555
   2.1    -2.2222                     -2.555
   3.1     3.2222  -3.03   more text   3.555
   4.1             -4.03              -4.555
                             no data   0.000
   6.1    -6.2222   6.03  no comment  -6.555
```

**Script:** (requires gnuplot>=5.2.0, Result basically like the graph above)

```
### read/plot data with fixed column width
reset session

FILE = 'SO58245920.dat'

# get the file 1:1 into a datablock
FileToDatablock(f,d) = GPVAL_SYSNAME[1:7] eq "Windows" ? \
                       sprintf('< echo   %s ^<^<EOD  & type "%s"',d,f) : \
                       sprintf('< echo "\%s   <<EOD" & cat  "%s"',d,f)     # Linux/MacOS
load FileToDatablock(FILE,'$Data')

colWidths     = "6 11 7 12 8"              # specify the fixed column widths
colStarts     = (s='1', s0=0, sum[i=1:words(colWidths)] (s0=s0+word(colWidths,i),s=s.' '.(s0+1),0),s)
colStart(col) = int(word(colStarts,col))
commentChar   = "#"

fcol(col)    = real((i=int($0+1), $Data[i][1:1] eq commentChar ? NaN : \
               $Data[i][colStart(col):colStart(col)+word(colWidths, col)-1].'NaN'))
fstrcol(col) = (i=int($0+1), $Data[i][1:1] eq commentChar ? '' : \
               $Data[i][colStart(col):colStart(col)+word(colWidths, col)-1])

set datafile commentschar ''
set datafile missing NaN
set key noautotitle
set offset 1,1,1,1

plot $Data u (fcol(1)):(fcol(5)) w lp pt 7 lc "red", \
        '' u (fcol(1)):(fcol(5)):(fstrcol(4)) w labels offset 0,1.0
### end of script
```

Answer (score 1):

gnuplot has always had the option to specify a format following the `using` spec, but the implementation predates the introduction of string variables.  So you can read numbers from a line with fixed width fields, but I can't immediately see how to read the field content as a string in the same command. Input scanning uses the C language routine sscanf(). Numbers always require format spec `%lf`. To skip an N character field use format spec `%*Nc`.

```
$DataRaw <<EOD
# Data with fixed but also empty columns
#0000000011111111112222222222333333333344444
#2345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
#--6-||----11---||--7--||-----12---||--8---|
   1.1     1.2222   1.03   some Text   1.555
   2.1    -2.2222                     -2.555
  -3.1     3.2222  -3.03   more text   3.555
   4.1             -4.03              -4.555
                             no data   0.000
   6.1    -6.2222   6.03  no comment  -6.555
EOD

set table 
splot $DataRaw skip 4 using 1:2:3:(sprintf("%g",$4)) "%6lf%11lf%7lf%*12c%8lf" with labels
```

produces

```
# Surface 0 of 1 surfaces

# Curve title: "$DataRaw skip 4 using 1:2:3:(sprintf("%g",$4)) "%6lf%11lf%7lf%*12c%8lf""
 1.1  1.2222  1.03 "1.555"
-3.1  3.2222 -3.03 "3.555"
 6.1 -6.2222  6.03 "-6.555"
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this. Unfortunately, it doesn't help because it can't read text and skips the whole row if there is an empty columns instead of inserting, e.g. empty space or `NaN`.