# Gnuplot pngcairo terminal doesn't plot data on the borders?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to create a png from a matrix using the pngcairo terminal, where each entry in the matrix is the colour of a single pixel in the image. For that purpose, I remove the border, tics, labels etc.

However, it seems that terminal always assumes the border takes the space of the first layer of pixels around the image and doesn't plot the data there, or does something funny there (antialiasing? I don't think so because it doesn't do the same blue smudge inside the image).

Here is a MWE (using transparent to highlight the issue):

```
set term pngcairo transparent size 7, 7
set margins 0,0,0,0
unset border
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
unset colorbox
unset key
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "blue") maxcolors 2
set output 'test.png'
set xrange [0:6]
set yrange [0:6]

plot '-' matrix with image notitle
1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1
e
unset output
```

The result is a 7x7 pixel image whose magnification (using an image viewer with checkerboard background) is
[image: test.png zoomed in]

What I would expect instead is
[image]
which is obtained by creating a 70x70 pixel image, offsetting the origin by 0.5 along each axis `using (0.5+$1):(0.5+$2):3`, and extending the `xrange` and `yrange` to `[0:7]`. You will note that there is still a 1 pixel layer of background around the image, where the data is not plotted.

Is there any way to use the data from the matrix to plot on the border using this terminal?

I am using Gnuplot 5.4 patchlevel 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost identical to this: [gnuplot: how to plot one 2D array element per pixel with no margins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59056181/7295599), however, the input data source is different.
So, my insight from there: it will not work with `terminal pngcairo`, but it will work with `terminal png`.

**Script:**

```
### plot png pixel graph without borders
reset session
OUTPUT = "SO76419284.png"

$Data <<EOD
1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   0   0   0   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   0   1   1
1   1   1   0   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1
EOD

stats $Data u 0 nooutput
sizeX = STATS_columns
sizeY = STATS_records
set term png transparent size sizeX, sizeY
set output OUTPUT
set margins 0,0,0,0
unset border
unset colorbox
unset key
unset tics
unset xlabel
unset ylabel
set xrange [0:sizeX-1]
set yrange [0:sizeY-1]
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "blue") maxcolors 2

plot $Data matrix u 1:2:3 w p pt 5 ps 0.1 lc palette
unset output
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

(32x magnified)

[image]

**Addition:**

Thanks to @armando.sano, I got some more insight.
The `terminal pngcairo` doesn't really work even when using a smaller pointsize. I tested different pointsizes.

`pngcairo` `ps 0.1`

[image]

`pngcairo` `ps 0.01`

[image]

`pngcairo` `ps 0.001` but if you check the exact color, there will be still pixels with `#efefff` and `#0202ff`.

[image]

However, if I set `ps 0.0006` I will get just a white image.

`pngcairo` `ps 0.0006`

[image]

So, for me (Win10, gnuplot 5.4.0) `terminal pngcairo` doesn't work.

In contrast, if you check the above output from `terminal png` and `ps 0.1` you clearly have only `#ffffff` and `#0000ff` pixels.

Comment: Great find, thank you, I searched but didn't find this one. Lots of different workarounds - the accepted answer at the link is awkward, yours @theozh works a treat: replacing the plot command in my initial script with `plot '-' matrix using 1:2:3 with points pt 5 ps 0.001 lc palette notitle` does the job. (`ps` needs to be very small but not zero, `ps 0.1` still shows some bluish tones in the middle). Possibly `png` terminal is better?

Comment: @armando.sano thank you for the feedback. Well, `terminal pngcairo` does not work perfectly, there will be always some blueish/whiteish tones. I will add some examples. Whereas `terminal png` seems to work as expected as far as I can tell.