# Generate Gnuplot Datablock by Shell command

Tags: shell, gnuplot

I have a rather costly shell command which generates some output which is supposed to be plotted.  The output contains information for several curves, e. g. like this:

```
echo 1 2 3; echo 4 5 6; echo 7 8 9
```

They are supposed to be plotted using a command like this:

```
plot <something> using 1:2, \
     <something> using 1:3
```

To avoid calling the shell command repeatedly (as it is rather slow), I want to store its result in a datablock, but up to now my trials didn't work.  Here is what I tried:

```
output = system("echo 1 2 3; echo 4 5 6; echo 7 8 9")
set print $DATA
print output
unset print
```

Now I *seem* to have a datablock containing what I want because `print $DATA` now prints this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

The trailing blank line I hope isn't a problem but maybe it indicates that there is something wrong, I don't know.

When I now try to plot this with `plot $DATA using 1:2` I only get the first of the three expected points (1|2), (4|5), and (7|8).

I feel there is probably an easier way to achieve my original goal but up to now I didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I *seem* to have a datablock containing what I want because `print $DATA` now prints this:
>
> ```
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6 
> 7 8 9
> ```

No, `$DATA` does not contain what you want. `$DATA` **should be** an array with **three elements**: 1st element is `1 2 3`, 2nd element is `4 5 6`, and 3rd one is `7 8 9`. Instead, the combination of `output = system("...")`, `set print $DATA`, and `print output` generates an array with **only one element**: `1 2 3\n4 5 6\n7 8 9`, printing into a datablock does not split the string into separate lines.

The difference is not visible with `print $DATA`. Both, a new array element of the datablock as well as a `\n` within an array element generate a linebreak.

You can use the `load '< XXXXX'` command to generate a useful datablock. From the gnuplot documentation:

> The `load` command executes each line of the specified input file as if it had been typed in interactively.
>
> ...
>
> On some systems which support a popen function (Unix), the load file can be read from a pipe by starting the file     name with a '<'.

The "XXXXX" can be a series of shell commands which generate the necessary gnuplot commands:

```
load '< echo "\$DATA << EOD" && echo 1 2 3; echo 4 5 6; echo 7 8 9 && echo "EOD"'
print $DATA
plot $DATA using 1:2 pt 5, $DATA using 1:3 pt 7
```

(inspired by [gnuplot: load datafile 1:1 into datablock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54600172))

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your problem correctly, I see three versions where versions 2 and 3 should work. I guess version 2 is what you wanted to avoid. Why the 1st version does not work I only can guess. My suspicion is something with the line end character. There seems to be a difference if you write to a datablock (version 1) or to a file (version 3). I remember a discussion with @Ethan about this... but I still don't understand myself. I assume you're working with Linux, in Windows `&` is used instead of `;`.

**Code:**

```
### system output to datablock
reset session

# Version 1
set title "Version 1: only plots 1st data line"
output = system("echo 1 2 3 & echo 4 5 6 & echo 7 8 9")   # in Windows "&" instead of ";"
set print $Data
    print output
set print
plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7
pause -1

# Version 2
set title "Version 2: several system calls"
set print $Data
    print system("echo 1 2 3")
    print system("echo 4 5 6")
    print system("echo 7 8 9")
set print
plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7
pause -1

# Version 3
set title "Version 3: writing into data file"
output = system("echo 1 2 3 & echo 4 5 6 & echo 7 8 9")   # in Windows "&" instead of ";"
set print "Data.dat"
    print output
set print
plot "Data.dat" u 1:2 w lp pt 7

### end of code
```

Comment: Thanks for your analysis.  Good to know that the OS is playing a role here. 
 Can't say much for Windows because you're right, I'm using Linux.  But on Linux Version 1 produces a datablock which appears to be of a single line, no matter which line end markers the shell command produces (I tried the Linux typical LF and also the Windows typical CR-LF, with equal results).  Version 2 I cannot use, my shell command is a single one.  Version 3 would be a workaround with all the drawbacks temp files always have.