# How to get key bind to work in gnuplot dumb terminal?

Tags: terminal, gnuplot

I tried to implement a plotting loop in the text terminal `dumb`.
In order to stop the loop I'm using `bind` (check `help bind`).
This works fine, e.g. in a `wxt` terminal, however, the loop will not stop when using the `dumb` terminal.

I know that I could stop the loop by pressing `Ctrl+C`, however, it looks like no key bindings seem to be possible. Why is this? How to workaround?

**Code:**

```
### key bind in dumb terminal?
reset session
set term dumb 120,30

# random plot
set samples 20
plot '+' u 1:(rand(0)) w l ti strftime("%d.%m.%Y\n%H:%M:%S",time(0))

stop = 0
bind x "stop = 1"

while !stop {
    pause 1.5     # delay in seconds
    replot
}
### end of code
```

**Result:** (but loop will not stop by pressing `x` as it would in a `wxt` terminal)

```
    1 +---------------------------------------------------------------------+   
      |                 +                +                 +                |   
      |                       ***                        24.02.2021 ******* |   
  0.9 |-+                   **  *                        10:40:46         +-|   
      |                     *    *                                          |   
  0.8 |-+                  *     *                           *            +-|   
      |      ****          *     *           ***             *              |   
      |      *   *         *      *        **  *             **             |   
  0.7 |-+    *   *        *       *        *   *             **           +-|   
      |     *     *       *       *       *     *           *  *            |   
  0.6 |-+   *     *      *        *       *     *           *  *          +-|   
      |     *      *     *         *     *      *           *   *           |   
      |     *      *     *         **    *      *           *   *           |   
  0.5 |*+   *       *   *            ** *        *          *    *        +-|   
      |*    *       *   *               *        *    *     *    *          |   
      |*   *         ***               *         *   **    *     *         *|   
  0.4 |-*  *         *                           *   * *   *      *       +*|   
      | *  *                                     *  *  *   *      *        *|   
  0.3 |-+* *                                      **    *  *       *      *-|   
      |  * *                                      **    *  *       *      * |   
      |  **                                       *     *  *       *      * |   
  0.2 |-+ *                                              **         *    *+-|   
      |   *                                              **         *    *  |   
  0.1 |-+                                                 *          *   *+-|   
      |                                                   *          ****   |   
      |                 +                +                 +            *   |   
    0 +---------------------------------------------------------------------+   
     -10               -5                0                 5                10
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is going to work. From `help bind`:

> Note that `bind` is only available if gnuplot was compiled with **mouse support** and it is used by all **mouse-capable terminals**.

As far as I understand, the `dumb` terminal is not meant to be interactive. Therefore it is not "mouse-capable" and does not react on mouse actions or key strokes.

The source file `dumb.trm` has the lines

```
   #ifdef USE_MOUSE
      , NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

which (I think) supports my assumption: Even if your gnuplot version has general mouse support, `bind` can't be used within the `dumb` terminal.

Comment: thank you for checking... well, it's not a mouse action, but a key stroke. `Ctrl+C` works as well, so, why shouldn't `Ctrl+A` work or just `a`? Anyway, probably that's how it is...(currently)...

Comment: @theozh It seems that the borderline is between **interactive** and **not interactive**. Mouse and key strokes are on the same side (on the interactive one). I have edited the answer to emphasize this. The 'Ctrl-C' (SIGINT) is special and it is handled by a separate signal handler. For example, you can interrupt a `fit` command which doesn't need any terminal at all.

Comment: ok, in my installation I see another terminal `caca` which should be an *interactive* text terminal (apparently still experimental, check `help caca`). There I can stop the loop by pressing `x`, however, I couldn't set the canvas size properly and it's freezing or crashing gnuplot :-(.