# Gnuplot: 3D plot from partially parametrized input

Tags: 3d, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a 3D plot from somewhat weird data. Assume you have a function `F(T,V) = a*T + b*V + c*V**2`, but those parameters in fact change for every `T`. So my data file looks like this:

```
#T a b c
0 a1 b1 c1
1 a2 b2 c2
2 a3 b3 c3
...
```

(So, essentially, my function is parametrized in temperature *T* and volume *V*. But for every *T* that parametrization changes)

What I want to do is to plot this data, for example, but not necessarily, in a fenceplot like [this](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/fenceplot.html).

My best attempt of achiving this is

```
F1(T,V) = T
F2(T,V) = V
F3(T,V) = V**2

set yrange [3:4]

splot infile u 1:y:($2*F1(x,y) + $3*F2(x,y) + $4*F3(x,y))
```

which is terribly wrong in numerous places, but should show best what I want to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, my suggestion would be the following. The x-range is `V`. And `T`, `a`, `b`, and `c` are taken from your datafile.
In this case it is of advantage if you have your data in a datablock.
In case you have it in a file, see here: [gnuplot: load datafile 1:1 into datablock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54600172/7295599)

Depending on your data loop your data lines forward or reverse (here reverse: `for [i=|$Data|:1:-1]`) for not fully covering some other curve. Note that there is no headerline in the datablock, otherwise you would have to loop from `[i=|$Data|:2:-1]`. Check the following minimal example for further tuning...

**Code:**

```
### parametric plot with zerrorfill
reset session

#T    a    b     c
$Data <<EOD
 0  1.1  2.1  0.1
 1  1.2  2.2  0.2
 2  1.3  2.3  0.3
 3  1.4  2.4  0.4
 4  1.5  2.5  0.5
 5  1.6  2.6  0.6
EOD

T(i) = real(word($Data[i],1))
a(i) = real(word($Data[i],2))
b(i) = real(word($Data[i],3))
c(i) = real(word($Data[i],4))
F(i,V) = a(i)*T(i) + b(i)*V + c(i)*V**2

set xyplane relative 0
set xrange [0:20]

splot for [i=|$Data|:1:-1] '+' u 1:(T(i)):(0):(0):(F(i,$1)) with zerrorfill notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Lot's of new gnuplot concepts to learn here, but it does nicely what I asked. Now I have to make sense of my data ;)