# Plotting large text file containing a matrix with gnuplot/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuplot, armadillo

For debugging purposes my program writes out the armadillo-based matrices in a raw-ascii format into text files, i.e. complex numbers are written as `(1, 1)`. Moreover, the resulting matrices result in file sizes > 3 GByte.

I would like to "plot" those matrices (representing fields) such that I can look at different points within the field for debugging. What would be the best way of doing that?

When directly plotting my file with gnuplot using

```
plot "matrix_file.txt" matrix with image
```

I get the response

```
warning: matrix contains missing or undefined values
Warning: empty cb range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]
```

I also could use Matplotlib, iterate over each row in the file and convert the values into appropriate python values, but I assume reading the full file doing that will be rather time-consuming.

Thus, are there other reasonable fast options for plotting my matrix, or is there a way to tell gnuplot how to treat my complex numbers properly?

A part of the first line looks like

```
(0.0000000000000000e+00,0.0000000000000000e+00) (8.6305562282169946e-07,6.0526580514090297e-07) (1.2822974500623326e-05,1.1477679031930141e-05) (5.8656372718492336e-05,6.6626342814082442e-05) (1.6183121649896915e-04,2.3519364967920469e-04) (3.2919257507746272e-04,6.2745022681547850e-04) (5.3056616247733281e-04,1.3949688132772061e-03) (6.7714688179733437e-04,2.7240206117506108e-03) (6.0083005524875425e-04,4.8217990806492588e-03) (3.6759450038482363e-05,7.8957232784174231e-03) (-1.3887302495780910e-03,1.2126758313515496e-02) (-4.1629396217170980e-03,1.7638346107957101e-02) (-8.8831593853181175e-03,2.4463072133103888e-02) (-1.6244140097742808e-02,3.2509486873735290e-02) (-2.7017231109227786e-02,4.1531431496659221e-02) (-4.2022691198292300e-02,5.1101686500864850e-02) (-6.2097364532786636e-02,6.0590740956970250e-02) (-8.8060067117896060e-02,6.9150058884242055e-02) (-1.2067637255414780e-01,7.5697648270160053e-02) (-1.6062285417043359e-01,7.8902435158400494e-02) (-2.0844826713055306e-01,7.7163461035715558e-02) (-2.6452596415873003e-01,6.8580842184681204e-02) (-3.2898869195273894e-01,5.0918234150147214e-02) (-4.0163477687695504e-01,2.1561405580661022e-02) (-4.8179470918233597e-01,-2.2515842273449008e-02) (-5.6815035401912617e-01,-8.4759639628930100e-02) (-6.5850621484774385e-01,-1.6899215347429869e-01) (-7.4952345707877654e-01,-2.7928561041518252e-01) (-8.3644196044174313e-01,-4.1972419090890900e-01) (-9.1283160402230334e-01,-5.9403043419268908e-01) (-9.7042844114238713e-01,-8.0504703287094281e-01) (-9.9912107865273936e-01,-1.0540865412492695e+00) (-9.8715384989307420e-01,-1.3401890190155983e+00) (-9.2160320921981831e-01,-1.6593576679224276e+00) (-7.8916051033438095e-01,-2.0038702251062159e+00) (-5.7721850912406181e-01,-2.3617835609973805e+00) (-2.7521347260072193e-01,-2.7167550691449942e+00)
```

Ideally, I would like to be able to choose if I plot only the real part, the imaginary part or the `abs()`-value.

Comment: You say the file is large... but maybe you can show a very little excerpt? A minimal example with data would be good. I guess the problems are the complex numbers. First of all, complex numbers in gnuplot are written e.g. `{1,1}` but I guess they cannot be plotted directly. How do you want them to be plotted? The real-part or the imaginary-part?

Comment: @theozh: I added an example and what I would like to be able to plot

Comment: ok, thank you. Actually, what do you want to plot? The column number as x, the row number as y and the absolute value of your complex number (`=sqrt(Re^2+Im^2)` as color or anything else?

Comment: Either just the real part, the imaginary part or the absolute value of my complex number as color, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a gnuplot only version.
Actually, I haven't seen (yet) a gnuplot example about how to plot complex numbers from a datafile.
Here, the idea is to split the data into columns at the characters `(` and `,` and `)` via:

```
set datafile separator '(,)'
```

Then you can address your i-th real and imaginary parts in column via `column(3*i-1)` and `column(3*i)`, respectively.

You are creating a new dataset via plotting the data many times in a double loop, which is ok for small data. However, my guess would be that this solution might become pretty slow for large datasets, especially if you are plotting from a file. I assume if you have your data once in a datablock (instead of a file) it might be faster. Check [gnuplot: load datafile 1:1 into datablock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54600172/7295599). In general, maybe it is more efficient to use another tool, e.g. Python, awk, etc. to prepare the data.

Just a thought: if you have approx. 3e9 Bytes of data and (according to your example) approx. 48-50 Bytes per datapoint and if you want to plot it as a square graph, then the number of pixels on a side would be `sqrt(3e9/50)=7746` pixels. I doubt that you have a display which can display this at once.

**Edit:**

The modified version below is now using `set print` to datablock and is much faster then the original version (using a double loop of `plot ... every ...`). The speed improvement I can already see with my little data example. Good luck with your huge dataset ;-).
Just for reference and comparison, the old version listed again here:

```
# create a new datablock with row,col,Real,Imag,Abs
# using plot ...with table     (pretty slow and inefficient)
set table $Data2
    set datafile separator '(,)'          # now, split your data at these characters
    myReal(i) = column(3*i-1)
    myImag(i) = column(3*i)
    myAbs(i)  = sqrt(myReal(i)**2 + myImag(i)**2)
    plot for [row=0:rowMax-1] for [col=1:colMax] $Data u (row):(col):(myReal(col)):(myImag(col)):(myAbs(col)) every ::row::row w table
    set datafile separator whitespace     # set separator back to whitespace
unset table
```

**Code:**  (modified using `set print`)

```
### plotting complex numbers
reset session

$Data <<EOD
(0.1,0.1)   (0.2,1.2)   (0.3,2.3)   (0.4,3.4)   (0.5,4.5)
(1.1,0.1)   (1.2,1.2)   (1.3,2.3)   (1.4,3.4)   (1.5,4.5)
(2.1,0.1)   (2.2,1.2)   (2.3,2.3)   (2.4,3.4)   (2.5,4.5)
(3.1,0.1)   (3.2,1.2)   (3.3,2.3)   (3.4,3.4)   (3.5,4.5)
(4.1,0.1)   (4.2,1.2)   (4.3,2.3)   (4.4,3.4)   (4.5,4.5)
(5.1,0.1)   (5.2,1.2)   (5.3,2.3)   (5.4,3.4)   (5.5,4.5)
(6.1,0.1)   (6.2,1.2)   (6.3,2.3)   (6.4,3.4)   (6.5,4.5)
(7.1,0.1)   (7.2,1.2)   (7.3,2.3)   (7.4,3.4)   (7.5,4.5)
EOD

stats $Data u 0 nooutput   # get number of columns and rows, separator is whitespace
colMax = STATS_columns
rowMax = STATS_records

# create a new datablock with row,col,Real,Imag,Abs
# using print to datablock
set print $Data2
    myCmplx(row,col) = word($Data[row+1],col)
    myReal(row,col) = (s=myCmplx(row,col),s[2:strstrt(s,',')-1])
    myImag(row,col) = (s=myCmplx(row,col),s[strstrt(s,',')+1:strlen(s)-1])
    myAbs(row,col)  = sqrt(myReal(row,col)**2 + myImag(row,col)**2)
    do for [row=0:rowMax-1] {
        do for [col=1:colMax] {
            print sprintf("%d %d %s %s %g",row-1,col,myReal(row,col),myImag(row,col),myAbs(row,col))
        }
    }
set print

set key box opaque

set multiplot layout 2,2
    plot $Data2 u 1:2:3 w image ti "Real part"
    plot $Data2 u 1:2:4 w image ti "Imaginary part"
    set origin 0.25,0
    plot $Data2 u 1:2:5 w image ti "Absolute value"
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: That's a nice solution, will test it as soon as possible!

Comment: @arc_lupus Some concern about this solution together with large data. Actually, the datablock `$Data2` is further blown up because it contains `row`,`col`,`Real`,`Imag`, and `Abs`. If your system is overstrained with your dataset, I would suggest to create a Real-only-matrix, a Imag-only-matrix, and an Abs-only-matrix in separate gnuplot scripts for plotting.

Comment: @arc_lupus since you accepted the answer, I assume it worked with your 3 GB datafile...? Glad to hear that gnuplot can handle this.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not what you asked for but I think it is neat to plot directly from your code and it is simple to modify what you want to show `abs(x),real(x),...` Here is a simple snippet to plot an Armadillo matrix as an image in gnuplot (Linux)

```
#include <armadillo>
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

void plot_image(mat& x, FILE* cmd_pipe)
{    
  fputs("set nokey;set yrange [*:*] reverse\n", cmd_pipe);
  fputs("plot '-' matrix with image\n", cmd_pipe);
  for(uword r=0; r<x.n_rows; r++){
    for(uword c=0; c<x.n_cols; c++){
      string str=to_string(x(r,c))+" ";
      fputs(str.c_str(), cmd_pipe);
    }
    fputs("\n", cmd_pipe);
  }
  fputs("e\n", cmd_pipe);
}

int main()
{
  FILE* gnuplot_pipe = popen("gnuplot -persist","w");
    
  mat x={{1,2,3,4,5},
         {2,2,3,4,5},
         {3,3,3,4,5},
         {4,4,4,4,5},
         {5,5,9,9,9}};
       
  plot_image(x,gnuplot_pipe);        
  return 0 ;    
}
```

The output is:
[image]